# add transition animation to a horizontal sliding navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, css-transitions

I have a navbar with a list of buttons in it. Upon clicking the right arrow button my list moves indexes to the right. This is how navbar lookslike by default:
[image]

And this is how it looks like after you click on the arrow button on the right:
[image]
At the moment the transition is instant. I want to make transition to look like a sliding effect something that gives the user the feeling that the buttons are sliding smoothly to the left. How can I do that?

This is my navbar:

```
<template>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">
      <form
        class="form-inline"
        v-for="(genre, index) in genres.slice(one, twenty)"
        :key="index"
      >
        <button class="btn btn-outline-dark m-1" type="button">
          {{ genre }}
        </button>
      </form>
      <a class="pashmi" @click="loadLeft">
        <img src="~/assets/Arrow-Scroll.svg" />
      </a>
    </nav>
</template>

<style scoped>
  .pashmi {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
  }
</style>
```

And this is my genre list and `one` and `twenty` variables:

```
data() {
    return {
      one: 0,
      twenty: 19,
      genres: [
        "ONE",
        "TWO",
        // goes until FOURTY
      ]
    }
}
```

And using this method I move the index to right:

```
methods: {
  loadLeft() {
    this.one++;
    this.twenty++;
  }
}
```

Comment: In order to create a transition you should move the elements instead of re-rendering them. A way to do this is to wrap the moving elements in a single element that moves left and right with the CSS `transform` property. Like an elevator that moves the people inside of it. Or use the [CSS Scroll Snap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap) module to scroll to the position of an element you want to scroll to.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any tutorial or videos I can get some help from?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But, the behavior you're looking for is basically the same that of a slider / carousel. There will definitely be a package available for Vue.js